# Triple booting Debian (wheezy) with Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, grub, multi-boot

I already have Windows 7(two systems) and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (desktop version) installed on my desktop, and would like to add Debian  Wheezy to that list.

Info related to my question:

1. The Desktop only has one hard drive (1GB), so lots of space
2. The GRUB menu currently controls which OS boots up
3. When I originally decided to dual boot(Ubuntu and Windows 7 systems), I already had two Windows 7 systems installed and I re-partitioned my hard drive and installed Ubuntu on the new partition.

Anyone can help me how to install correct way Second Linux system( Debian Wheezy) without screwing up couple of Windows 7 and Ubuntu?

Thank you.

Comment: A 1GB hard drive? That isn't a lot. You missing a few zeros there?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do would be to create a new partition for Debian's root (/). Then install Debian onto that partition.

You can use the same /home folder on both GNU/Linux systems (assuming /home is on a separate partition). That way, if your Debian user name is the same as your Ubuntu one, all your settings will be there the first time you log in.

The Debian installer will probably try and install GRUB2 again. Let it do so. It should automatically detect the other installed OSs and add them to the bootloader's configuration.